# Why did my nickel + hydrogen peroxide turn red?

Tags: electrochemistry

So I recently thought of doing some electroplating and bought some nickel strips from Amazon. As I was making the acetate solution I added some hydrogen peroxide (6%) because I wanted to see if nickel would form nickel acetate the same way copper acetate is made by reacting copper with acetic acid (I had disconnected power). To my absolute surprise the color of the solution changed from crystal clear to almost blood-like red.

Could someone tell me what products I may have made?

Could it be that my nickel was not pure and contained some impurities? The seller claims it's 96% pure and its the sort you'd use for spot welding but I'm not sure.

Comment: [Nickel(II) acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel(II)_acetate) is green. // One of hypothesis is it could be a red-brown [basic iron(III) acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_acetate) ( *The formation of the red-brown complex was once used as a test for ferric ions.* ). // Another question is, if $\ce{H2O2}$ forms Nickel(III,IV) or some peroxocomplex.

Comment: Nickel, especially in solution, is sort of *unheathly*, if you get my drift. I hope you wear gloves if there is any danger of getting it on your fingers, and have a environment-friendly plan for it's disposal.

Comment: Tell us exactly what you have done. All you say is that ... "as I was making the acetate solution". Well. When did the color change ? What else did you observe ? Any precipitate ?

Comment: Some nickel compounds are red, like nickel chlorate $\ce{Ni(ClO3)2·6H2O}$